# UserControl RoutedEvent execute in VIewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I got a UserControl with following code inside:

```
        public static readonly RoutedEvent DetailClickEvent =
       EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DetailClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(SXUserControl));



    public event RoutedEventHandler DetailClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(DetailClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(DetailClickEvent, value); }
    }

    private void ShowDetail_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((FrameworkElement)sender).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(DetailClickEvent));

    }
```

The UserControl is used in my MainView. There I give it a Methode to code-behind.

```
<Window.....
        Resources:SXUserControl.DetailClick="Detail_Click"
....
</Window>
```

How can I bind a Methode from the ViewModel? Or is it possible to bind a RelayCommand?
When I try to bind to a Methode like

```
        Resources:SXUserControl.DetailClick="{Binding test123}"
```

i get an error

> Inner Exception 1: InvalidCastException: Das Objekt des Typs
> "System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo" kann nicht in Typ
> "System.Reflection.MethodInfo" umgewandelt werden.

Comment: I would go with some implementation of icommand. Relay or delegate command.

Comment: RelayCommand throws me an error in the IDE "Event 'DetailClick' can only be bound to properties of delegate type 'RoutedEventHandler'

Comment: Usual to bind a command property to an icommand. Buttons have command support built in. And are contentcontrols. Wpf controls are lookless so you can re template entirely. Maybe you should consider a book on wpf.

Comment: The "DetailClick" in the code is already a MouseDoubleClick on a Button.
But a MouseDoubleClick is an Event, and not a command. So ICommand is not working on an Event